Quickest known integer relation algorithm in the case of signs
Let $x_1,\cdots,x_n,k$ be integers such that $|k|\le\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$.
What is the quickest known algorithm to determine $w_i\in\{-1,0,1\}$ such that $k=\sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_i$ where they exist?
What is its asymptotic as $n\to\infty$?
These algorithms apply more generally to $w_i\in\Bbb Z$ and $x_i\in\Bbb R$ so perhaps this case has a faster algorithm.

In the case the variables are integer, one possible way would be similar to finding the solutions on the system of linear equations. I am unsure about its algorithm, but it can be done by any standard MIP/MINLP solver.
